# select all corresponding data

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to select all products with that brand id but only one is coming.

**model code**

```
public function get_product_by_brid($id)    {       
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('product p'); 
  $this->db->join('category c', 'c.CategoryId=p.CategoryId', 'left');
  $this->db->join('brand s', 'p.BrandId=s.BrandId', 'left');             
  $this->db->where('p.BrandId',$id);        
  $query  $this->db->get();
  return $query->row();     
}
```

**controller code**

```
public function ajax_delete($id)
{
    $brand = $this->brand->get_by_id($id);

    $productsunderbrand = $this->brand->get_product_by_brid($id);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($productsunderbrand);
    exit();
    $this->brand->delete_by_id($id);
    echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
}
```

Comment: can you update the question with clear information?

Comment: want to select all product with that brand id but only one is comimg

Comment: Have you tried without brand ID. How many products are retrieving?

Comment: all are coming with out brand id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return $query->row();
```

return row will only return you one result.

try

```
return $query->result();
```

or

```
return $query->result_array();
```